# ribbon combobox lose the value in the reload

Tags: vb.net

The object is to create a combobox for a new appointment. The combobox displays the list of course names. The problem is when I load the new appointment, the combobox displays the list of course name, but once I create another one (appointment) combobox did not display the list.

---

The code :

```
    If Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.ComboBox1.Items.Count = 0 Then
         For Each cell In exlWorkSheet.Range(exlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 1), exlWorkSheet.Cells(nombreLigne, 1))
            item1 = Me.Factory.CreateRibbonDropDownItem()
            item1.Label = (CType(cell.value, String)) 'Appel au méthode
            Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.ComboBox1.Items.Add(item1)
            Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Items : " & item1.ToString)
            Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("ComboBox : " & Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.ComboBox1.Items.ToString)
        Next
        ComboBox1.Dispose()

    End If
```

Comment: `ComboBox1.Dispose()` why are you disposing this control after you add items?

Comment: it's just for test